JupyterLab conflicting with Notebook
this is my first question here so please be patient with me. I am having to use legacy, v6, Jupyter Notebook because it seems that the dependencies with JupyterLab are causing issues (ie. the UX won't allow me to open folders or really navigate to any files). Has anyone else experienced this issue and/or have you found a solution? For reference I'm on a Mac with an Intel chip. Thanks!
I attempted to install Anaconda which is taking me to the UX that is broken and so the only solution I found was to install v6. This works but without Anaconda my dependencies are a nightmare and I need to create a new virtual environment for each project which is becoming very difficult to keep track of.

What specific versions are involved? Normally, you'd want NbClassic that will work with current JupyterLab. However, you system sounds overly complicated at this time. Can you create another user on your machine and install there in a more fresh setting? It may be worth a try to install the Anaconda Distribution there and see if it works in the new user account. Be sure to launch Jupyter from inside the Anaconda Navigator if you try in the new account. If you need the classic interface in the new account, install NbClassic, but try Jupyter Notebook 7+ first. 7+ now comes with Anconda Distrib.

If you are using jupyter V6 you might need to make sure it "knows" about your new conda environments - see here for instructions if your new environment is not in the list of "kernels" in jupyter notebook interface: https://medium.com/@k.yara/how-to-set-up-a-conda-environment-with-a-jupyter-kernel-f9c963207491

Right now I'm using NBclassic but am trying to be able to get the most up to date Anaconda. When I go through Anaconda the UX breaks so I had to create a new environment and just get notebook v6

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
